# Why doesn't df show the filesystem disk space of the path that I give it?

Tags: disk-usage

I am trying to see the filesystem space in my system but even if I change location it still shows the same space. I see the man page and as far as I understand I am passing the right argument. Why is it still showing me not the space in the file (system) I give it?

```
(metalearning_gpu) brando9~ $ df -h anaconda
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
ilnfs1:/pool0/scratch0   53T   53T   14G 100% /dfs/scratch0
(metalearning_gpu) brando9~ $ cd anaconda/
(metalearning_gpu) brando9~/anaconda $ df -h .
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
ilnfs1:/pool0/scratch0   53T   53T   14G 100% /dfs/scratch0
```

man page:

```
NAME
       df - report file system disk space usage

SYNOPSIS
       df [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df` shows the space of the entire filesystem.  When you give it a path, it shows you the space for whole filesystem on which that path exists.

If you want to see the usage of the files only under a particular path, you should try the `du` command.  Specifically something like: `du -h -s .` or `du -h -s /path/to/my/directory`

*Edited to add:*
When you want both the size of the files under a certain path and also filesystem stats like the total space and available space, you can't use only `du` or `df`, you have to use them both:

- `df` shows the filesystem-level stats like total space and available space (but not the usage at the level of files and directories)
- `du` shows usage at the level of files and directories, but not the total/available space in the filesystem

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't show me the total available space too. It says X GB which is not helpful if I don't know how much there is in total anyway. How do I see that too?

Comment: Space is related to _partition_, not a directory

Comment: `du` doesn't show the total space and available space in the filesystem because it doesn't look at the filesystem stats.  `du` only adds up the sizes of the files you point it to.  `df` shows the total and available space in the filesystem, because it looks at the filesystem stats.  It doesn't look at the individual file sizes, so it can't show you the ones in the directory you're interested in.  Use `df` for the total and available space in the filesystem, and `du` for the space consumed in the directory path you're checking.

Comment: @SottoVoce add that in your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

credit to @sotto voco's answer but this is my understanding.

TLDR:

```
For space usage do:
df -h path2inode
above for systemfile usage

du -hs path2inode
du -hs ~ | grep data | head -5
du -hs ~ | sort rh | head -5
above for specific inode. Might be slow. 

To see space your using for specific files & total limit run both commands.
```

---

## df -sh path2file - shows the amount of space the filesystem that the path2file is mounted on, not space of path2file

So use df to see how much space you've used in the filesystem your stuff (or a specific file/inode) is mounted on. e.g.

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2p1       56T   13T   41T  24% /lfs/ampere4/0
```

so I interpret the above that the file/inode `.` (path is `/lfs/ampere4/0/brando9`) is mounted on the `/lfs/ampere4/0` and **it shows filesystem info of where that file is mounted -- not size/space info about the file itself.**

To quote some useful descriptions:

> df shows the total and available space in the filesystem, because it looks at the filesystem stats. (from sotto voce)

> df displays the amount of disk space available on the file system containing each file name argument. df - report file system disk space usage. (man page for df).

## du - shows the space of a given file/inode, cannot give you the info of the total filesystem your file/inode is mounted on

du shows space on a specific file/path/inode/dir. e.g.

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ du -hs .
8.7G    .
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ du -hs ~
8.7G    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando
```

to get the filesystem space your taken (e.g. your limits). Run both the `du -h ~` and `du -hs` one after another. If you remove `-s` the output is too many and you might need to sort it or grep it for the info you need. Examples at the end of this.

From the man page;

> Summarize disk usage of the set of FILEs, recursively for directories.

Common examples of `du`:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ du -h ~ | sort -rh | head -10
8.7G    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9
8.6G    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam
4.6G    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12
3.0G    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch
2.9G    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources
2.0G    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10
1.2G    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1
917M    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/menhirSdk.dev
917M    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/menhirLib.dev
917M    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/menhir.dev
```

or

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ du -h ~ | grep data
4.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/data
8.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/ignored_subdirs/pre-1.6.t/data
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/self-data-only.t
4.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t/dir
20K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/deep-subfolder-dataonly.t
116K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/menhirLib.dev/test/dynamic/semantics/data
116K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/menhir.dev/test/dynamic/semantics/data
8.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/ignored_subdirs/pre-1.6.t/data
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/self-data-only.t
4.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t/dir
20K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/deep-subfolder-dataonly.t
116K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/menhirSdk.dev/test/dynamic/semantics/data
8.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/ignored_subdirs/pre-1.6.t/data
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/self-data-only.t
4.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t/dir
20K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/deep-subfolder-dataonly.t
8.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/ignored_subdirs/pre-1.6.t/data
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/self-data-only.t
4.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t/dir
20K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/.opam-switch/sources/dune.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/deep-subfolder-dataonly.t
```

or shorter

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ du -h ~ | grep data | head -5
4.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/data
8.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/ignored_subdirs/pre-1.6.t/data
16K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/self-data-only.t
4.0K    /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t/dir
20K /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.12/.opam-switch/sources/dune-configurator.3.6.1/test/blackbox-tests/test-cases/vendor/conflicts-with-data-only.t
```